# Where Android SDK does install Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, android-ndk

I would like to use NDK for Android. I am trying to set up the hello world project. I have installed the Android bundle SDK verion, however I can't find the Eclipse which is supposed to be installed along with SDK (according to [NDK installation guide](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html)).
Android studio looks much like Eclipse, is this the Eclipse mentioned in NDK installation guide? However there is no window->preferences menu which is to be cofigured.

In Android Studio I have installed the NDK (in Tools->Android->SDK Manager) but I am not sure what that did.

Answer (score 0):

SDK bundle has Android Studio and no eclipse anymore.

You can try with writing NDK in Android Studio as it supports it and will sooner or later be default NDK IDE